# How to best decouple data base from application?

Tags: java, database, spring

We have a command and control system which persists historical data in a database. We'd like to make the system independent of the database. So if the database is there, great we will persist data there, if it is not, we will do some backup storage to files and memory until the database is back. The command and control functionality must be able to continue uninterrupted by the loss or restoration of the database; it should not even know the database exists. So the database and DAO functionality needs to be decoupled from the rest of the application.

We are using RESTful service calls, Spring framework, ActiveMQ, JDBCTemplate with SQL Server database. Currently following standard connection practices using Hikari datasource and JTDS driver. The problem is that if the database goes down or the database connection is lost we start to have data issues as too many service calls (mainly the getters) are still too dependent on the database existence for processing. This dependence is what we'd like to eliminate.

What are the best practices/technologies for totally decoupling the database from the application? We are considering using AMQ to broadcast data updates and have the DAO listen for those messages and then do the update to the database if it is available or flat files as a backup. Then for the getters, provide replies based on what is available either from the actual database or from the short-term backup.

My team has little experience with this and we want to know what others have done that works well.

Comment: This is a multi-step problem that requires a multi-step solution. You need to handle what happens when you no longer have a DB in your application. Does it use a cache of data stored in memory or on file? Will it include everything or X latest? Once you figure out how you're storing the data when there is no DB, it's much easier to do conflict resolution afterwards, since you can just play back all the DB update statements on the actual DB.

Comment: I see the word decoupling, but I feel like you really just want 'resilience'. Have you considered having multiple database instances with a way to fail-over between them? Most databases can replicate to facilitate this, and it would be a much simpler problem to tackle.

Comment: We actually want both - resilience and decoupling. Currently we are dealing with exceptions from the connection being lost, and with delayed / stopped processing from the dao calls hanging while waiting for the timeout. As for the resilience, we don't want to require database fail over for our system to run. It is deployed to customer's sites and that would be  requirement that we couldn't guarantee.

Comment: @Compass - we are currently discussing those exact questions and the big question that comes up is "What does everyone else do?" I'm suggesting only caching when the database is unavailable but there is no telling how long that could be. So it may be a combination of cache and flat files. Unless there is something else more elegant.